# Rounding off a float/double conditionally

Tags: c#, formatting, floating-point, double

I have a unique problem. I have a database with lot of tables and I am trying to do some comparison of each table with a file. now in certain cases my db contains double/float columns and they might exceed a certain no of decimal places than that of the same column in the file. Say for convenience sake we pick this no to be 4 decimal places.

Now I want to convert all float/double columns returned by my db to a string of 4 decimal places if its more than that.how can i achieve the same. Please note that each of ther table might contain in excesss of 2000 rows and I dont want to make this comparison heavy. Any idea how I can achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

Based on some answers and comments:

a) RDBMS: MS SQl server

b)I want the decimal places to only be cut short if it exceeds a certain no.  i.e if the no is 12.123 it should stat 12.123 and nt 12.1230

I realise I can get this done by using # but # just prints the no it doesnt round off the no i.e if the no is 12.12347 it should round off 12.1235

Comment: MS SQL server . How does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this for float limitation to a number of decimal places:

```
string stFloat = String.Format("{0:0.0000}", FLOAT_VALUE);
```

Apply this to the data that is received from the DB.

Comment: This is correct. Also note that you have a couple of different options for the string format. The full list is [given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), but the summary is as follows. A zero ("0") will replace the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present, otherwise it will leave a 0 in the returned string. A digit placeholder ("#") will replace the sign with the corresponding digit if one is present, otherwise no digit will appear in the returned string.

Comment: But if i dont want the trailing 0s then??

Comment: Also i want it to round off the no correctly i.e if it is 12.12347 then it should be 12.1235

Comment: TrimEnd is the answer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx

Comment: Not really sure why specifying "#" instead of "0" isn't the answer, but OK that will work, too. `val.ToString("N4");` is another possible option.